# Scanning a .cs file or a directory

Tags: c#

This is a console application which takes as an argument either a .cs file or a directory. If it's a .cs file, it scans it; if it's a directory, it scans all .cs files within the directory.

A simplified view of a method which chooses whether it's a file or a directory and reports errors is this one:

```
public static void ProcessPath(string path)
{
    if (path.EndsWith(".cs"))
    {
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            Program.ScanFile(path);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The specified file doesn't exist.");
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Program.ScanDirectory(path);
        }
        else
        {
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The path corresponds to a file, but only *.cs files are supported.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The specified directory doesn't exist.");
            }

            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I rewrite the `if/else` logic in a more elegant way? Would it improve readability?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In my opinion, the easiest way would be to *embrace* exceptions. `DirectoryNotFoundException` and `FileNotFoundException` are there for a reason, and actually even calling `.Exists` might not save you from them - the file might be moved/removed between the `Exists` and the action you're taking next.

You can do:

```
public static void ProcessPath(string path)
{
    var extension = Path.GetExtension(path);

    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(extension))
    {
        Program.ScanDirectory(path);
    }
    else
    {
        if(extension != ".cs")
            throw new NotSupportedException("Only .cs files are supported");

        Program.ScanFile(path);
    }
}
```

And either catch those exceptions higher up and write them to console or (considering you're doing `Environment.Exit` in your example), just let them propagate and crash the application.

Comment: +1 for exceptions. The notion of being able to code defensively against file system objects is a fallacy. There are absolutely no guarantees with the file system.

Comment: What if I want to scan the directory ".sharpDevelopProjects" or "backup 29.11.2013"?

Comment: @abuzittingillifirca Then the `GetExtension` fails, but you have no real way of distinguishing those cases unless you try to [get the attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1896995/1180426) from the filesystem.